# Swipe transition to go back works, but pressing the back button does not go back

Tags: java, android, react-native, react-navigation, androidx

On swipe, the transition to go back works, but when i press the back button the transition does not work in Android OS.

I have used react-navigation v4 https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html

```
export const navStack = (screenName) => createStackNavigator({
    Screen1,
    Screen2,
    Screen3
}, {
    initialRouteName: screenName,
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
        ...TransitionPresets.SlideFromRightIOS,
        headerStyleInterpolator: HeaderStyleInterpolators.forUIKit,
        headerShown: false,
        gestureEnabled: true
    }
});
const AppTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    TabScreen1: {
        screen: navStack("Screen1")
    },
    TabScreen2: {
        screen: AnyScreen
    },
}, {
    initialRouteName: "TabScreen1",
    backBehavior: "none",
    tabBarOptions: {
        showLabel: false
    }
});
export const App = createAppContainer(AppTabNavigator);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think because of you set `backBehavior: "none"`
Just try setting it like `backBehavior: "initialRoute"` or `backBehavior: "history"`  it will redirect you back or initial stage try based on your requirement

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
I think backBehavior used for tap navigation. But still I tried to change to backBehavior: "initialRoute" or backBehavior: "history", it does not work.

I would like to see navigation inside createStackNavigator

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like goback method provided by react navigation library. you can create your custom back button and when click on it use `navigate.goBack()` function.

Comment: i tried to use in component `BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", this.onBack)` [source](https://codedaily.io/tutorials/57/Custom-Handling-the-Android-Back-Button-with-React-Navigation), but it is not work for me.

Comment: pass browserRouter as props to your component and do this.props.navigation.goBack() function, you dont have to create an event listener.

Please check the method: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#goback-close-the-active-screen-and-move-back

Comment: Did not understand you. I will be very impressive for a simple example :)

Comment: how do you go to another screen when you click on a button?

Comment: Perhaps we do not understand each other, I need an event to press the system button back on Android OS, not custom back button